# WebView load css on the fly

Tags: objective-c, webkit, webview

I have the following code which loads and html file into a webview

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{

    NSString *resourcesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *htmlPath = [resourcesPath stringByAppendingString:@"/main.html"];
    [[self mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]]];

}
```

How would i dynamically load a css file (in the most efficient manner) as it does not suit to have the css file link in the html file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should access the DOM using the Objective-C DOM API and insert the appropriate `<link>` or `<style>` element into the DOM.

```
DOMDocument* domDocument=[webView mainFrameDocument];
DOMElement* styleElement=[domDocument createElement:@"style"];
[styleElement setAttribute:@"type" value:@"text/css"];
DOMText* cssText=[domDocument createTextNode:@"body{font-weight:bold;}"];
[styleElement appendChild:cssText];
DOMElement* headElement=(DOMElement*)[[domDocument getElementsByTagName:@"head"] item:0];
[headElement appendChild:styleElement];
```

Comment: is it possible to use this to overwrite an existing style element (to use a custom style sheet instead of an existing css file)?

Comment: Almost certainly yes. There's nothing magic with this, it's just DOM manipulation of the style sheet elements.