# Inject Custom CSS and javascript into WebView

Tags: objective-c, css, cocoa, uiwebview, webview

How can I inject custom CSS into a WebView like changing the   `background-color:` of http://www.apple.com/. Javascript would also be nice because in the future I would like to have control of the javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be the one delineated by Rob Keniger, with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2475623/307881. This technique should also work for javascript. If it doesn't work off the bat try modifying the DOM after the WebView has finished loading (see below)

---

You can also directly evaluate a javascript string without accessing the DOM.

First, get your javascript string, then, when your WebView finishes loading its content, use the delegate method of `WebFrameLoadDelegate`:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    [sender stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsStringToInject];
}
```

Comment: the CSS part woks but not the JS

Comment: Did you try using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString? Or do both methods not work?

Comment: Do you get any errors? I currently use the second method and it works well - what javascript are you trying to embed?

Comment: I don't get any errors i'm just trying to test it using the js: `alert('Hello World!');`

Comment: Well, alert() has never worked for me in a WebView. Maybe stringByEvaluatingString doesn't support it.

Comment: this works: window.location.href=\"http://apple.com\ but I have an NSTimer that repeats for didFinishLoadForFrame: and it is also repeating the js every 0.2s, it doesn't let me make a duplicate of didFinishLoadForFrame: so now i'm kinda stuck :(

Comment: "repeating the js every 0.2s" - are you trying to execute a line of javascript every 0.2 seconds? Then you don't have to use didFinishLoadForFrame - the purpose of using didFinishLoad is to make sure the page has loaded before injecting the javascript.