# Submitting HTML forms from within a Mac Cocoa app

Tags: javascript, html, macos, cocoa, webkit

I am making a Mac app in Objective-C, and I need it to be able to submit a form (well, press a button) on a website, but all the user has to do is provide the time associated with the form.

Here is the code from the website:

```
<td class=t_h>07:16</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class=t_s  height='24'>
<form method="POST" action="members_booking.php?operation=member_booking_form" onSubmit="return ValidateMemberBookNow(this)">
<INPUT NAME=double_click TYPE=hidden>
<INPUT NAME=course_id TYPE=hidden VALUE="1">
<INPUT NAME=unique_id TYPE=hidden VALUE="230693">
<INPUT NAME=d_date    TYPE=hidden VALUE="2012-09-07">
<INPUT NAME=Booking_Operation TYPE=hidden VALUE="Book Casual">
<INPUT NAME=SubmitButton TYPE=submit VALUE="Book Now">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=t_h>07:24</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class=t_s  height='24'>
<form method="POST" action="members_booking.php?operation=member_booking_form" onSubmit="return ValidateMemberBookNow(this)">
<INPUT NAME=double_click TYPE=hidden>
<INPUT NAME=course_id TYPE=hidden VALUE="1">
<INPUT NAME=unique_id TYPE=hidden VALUE="230694">
<INPUT NAME=d_date    TYPE=hidden VALUE="2012-09-07">
<INPUT NAME=Booking_Operation TYPE=hidden VALUE="Book Casual">
<INPUT NAME=SubmitButton TYPE=submit VALUE="Book Now">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=t_h>07:32</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class=t_s  height='24'>
<form method="POST" action="members_booking.php?operation=member_booking_form" onSubmit="return ValidateMemberBookNow(this)">
<INPUT NAME=double_click TYPE=hidden>
<INPUT NAME=course_id TYPE=hidden VALUE="1">
<INPUT NAME=unique_id TYPE=hidden VALUE="230695">
<INPUT NAME=d_date    TYPE=hidden VALUE="2012-09-07">
<INPUT NAME=Booking_Operation TYPE=hidden VALUE="Book Casual">
<INPUT NAME=SubmitButton TYPE=submit VALUE="Book Now">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

There can be up to 40 of these blocks. The `<td class=t_h>07:32</td>` is the time the user has specified. I need the button associated with that time to be pressed automatically. How?

thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of problem where [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) comes into its own. The basic idea is to find the element of class `t_h` with the text `07:32`. Then, in its parent node, find a `form` element and `submit()` it.

Here you go:

```
function submitFormForTime(time){
    $(".t_h").each(function(i, obj){ // find each element with the class t_h
        if ($(this).text() != time) return; // not the right one
        $(this).parent().find("form").each(function(i, obj){
            obj.submit(); // submit that form
        });
    });
}

submitFormForTime("07:32");
```

Add this script to the website. To call this script from Objective-C see:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html

From the above documents, the following will call the JavaScript function from Objective-C:

```
id win = [webView yourWebView]; // assumes your webView is called yourWebView
[win evaluateWebScript:@"submitFormForTime('07:32');"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer! I really appreciate it. After a solid hour of research and trial&error, I am still very confused as to how I should call it from inside the objective-c code. I'm no javaScript buff, but from what I see in the Apple docs, there is no information on calling full functions with variables (such as the time in this case). Any more pointers in the right direction would be strongly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, Conor. About calling JavaScript from Objective-C, see the example at the end of the linked document. I've updated the answer with example code.

Comment: Thanks, but please answer this one last question: Calling the function  with the time variable is no issue, but how do I implement the function in the first place? I have it set up in a separate .js file in my resources, but how do I make this interact with the current page being displayed in the webView? thanks once again

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I think you misunderstood my question, or maybe I wasn't clear enough. I do not own the website, I just want to access it to press the button in the form

Comment: You will need to "inject" your JS into the website. That can be tricky because of security issues. See here for a tutorial: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview JS injection is an issue of its own. Another question, which may be of help is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730986/inject-custom-css-and-javascript-into-webview