# Embedded Tweet not displaying properly in UIWebView swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, twitter, uiwebview

I am getting a HTML in a key of JSON response from API call. I load that HTML on UIWebView.

Everything is displayed but with "twitter-tweet" tag the view is not being created as tweet only text is shown.

[image]
 this is how i want to display on the simulaor but

[image]

This is how its being displayed.
The HTML which is coming like this

[image]

Comment: This looks like the css and the javascript is missing. Have you validated that you get these components also?

Comment: How can I add javascript in iOS inside this code? @weissja19

Comment: You could use the WKWebView (https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:). This is for interactive Web content and supports javascript out of the box. Do you have a <script> or <style> tag in your response?

Comment: If i want to use UIWebView, than?

Comment: I am using "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" for font size and color. but i am not able to use it for twitter tag can you suggest some links that would guide me how to use it.

Comment: If I understood your problem right it would be the best solution if you provide a css file and add it to your html content with the style tag. With this solution you don't have to manipulate the content from the webview api side and it should load like expected.  Here is a good example for adding a style tag inside your html content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475467/webview-load-css-on-the-fly/2475623#2475623

Comment: you found any solution for this? i am facing the same . Plz update

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me, please go step by step

Sample Twitter Resonse HTML Look like (Remove " in text to make correct string)

```
let responseTwitterHTMLContent = " <blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-width=\"500\">\n<p lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\"><a href=\"https:\/\/twitter.com\/kalyansury\">@kalyansury<\/a> Yes, last night. With a really lame and bleeding obvious response. I&#39;m thinking of my next steps. <a href=\"https:\/\/twitter.com\/HDFC_Bank\">@HDFC_Bank<\/a> <a href=\"https:\/\/twitter.com\/HDFCBank_Cares\">@HDFCBank_Cares<\/a><\/p>\n<p>&mdash; Karthik (@beastoftraal) <a href=\"https:\/\/twitter.com\/beastoftraal\/status\/826589530748813313\">February 1, 2017<\/a><\/p><\/blockquote> "
```

If your response doesn't include this twitter script

```
<script async src=\"\/\/platform.twitter.com\/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"><\/script>
```

Include twitter script like below in head tag programatically

```
<head><script async src=//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js charset=utf-8></script></head>
```

then final Modified HTML content look like

```
let ModifyHtmlcontent = "<html><head><script async src=//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js charset=utf-8></script><style></head><body style = width: 100%; height:auto; overflow:hidden; margin:100px; text-align:justify;>\(responseTwitterHTMLContent)</body></html>"
```

Load this content in webview

If I load above html it doesn't show twitter format look coz twitter script which we included above not downloaded by uiwebview for that you need to give base url **https:**

```
let url: URL = URL(string: "https:")!

self.yourWebView.loadHTMLString(ModifyHtmlcontent, baseURL: url)
```

If base url is creating problem then change the script add **https:** directly in twitter script  And make base url to nil

```
<head><script async src=https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js charset=utf-8></script></head>

self.yourWebView.loadHTMLString(ModifyHtmlcontent, baseURL: nil)
```

make sure you have given *script async*

Happy Coding!

[Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets/faq)