# How can I hide the google drive heading and options bar in iOS ( Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I want to hide the top options bar in google drive. How can I achieve that? I am using `UIWebView` to open this link.[image]

Comment: URL is:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nipvep1WpPd2JXeDdJcUlNYXM/view

Comment: I suppose you could inject some JavaScript into the webview. It'll probably break anytime Google changes their UI, though.

Comment: Please help how to handle in Javascript into webview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475467/webview-load-css-on-the-fly/

Answer (score 0):

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('drive-viewer-toolstrip')[0].style.visibility='hidden'"];
```

}